# NSDate dropping decimal with floorf produces strange output

Tags: objective-c, floor

I have a simple snippet which runs a loop every 1 second and displays seconds since epoch using NSDate.

```
        while(1){
            NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
            NSTimeInterval nowEpochSeconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
            NSLog(@"%f",nowEpochSeconds);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
        }
```

nowEpochSeconds produces a floating point value in seconds with several decimal places as such

```
1568646562.613972
1568646563.618479
1568646564.621624
1568646565.626183
1568646566.626722
1568646567.628425
1568646568.633329
```

It's very close to one second intervals. Then I try dropping the decimal place using floorf

```
NSLog(@"%f",floorf(nowEpochSeconds));
```

But the seconds just remain the same. It's not the correct number of seconds either they just stagnate at one value

```
1568646528.000000
1568646528.000000
1568646528.000000
1568646528.000000
1568646528.000000
1568646528.000000
```

I don't know why floorf is giving me strange results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTimeInterval` is a `double`, so you probably want to be using `floor()`:

```
int j = 0;
while(++j < 6){
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval nowEpochSeconds = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSLog(@"%f",nowEpochSeconds);
    NSLog(@"%f",floor(nowEpochSeconds));
    NSLog(@"\n");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
}
```

Output:

```
1568648630.428520
1568648630.000000

1568648631.429841
1568648631.000000

1568648632.431206
1568648632.000000

1568648633.432594
1568648633.000000

1568648634.433988
1568648634.000000
```

Comment: A `float` is only good for about 7 or 8 significant digits. So yes, rounding to a `float` would be a problem when there are 10 digits before the decimal.